# How to execute strftime in javascript ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, countdown

I am making a countdown counter where the user is entering the start date and duration and then the End date gets calculated. And based on this End date a countdown counter starts.

But the issue here is that the counter is giving the wrong output. The number of months, days, hours, min, sec everything is fine except the year. 
I think there is something wrong with my `srftime` command.

```
<script src="external/jquery/dateFormat.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="external/jquery/jquery.countdown.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#start_date").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
        $("#setCounter").on("click",function(){
            var startDate = $("#start_date").val();
            var duration = $("#period").val();
            if (startDate == "" || duration == "") {
                alert("Please fill all the fields.");
                return;
            }
            stopDate = new Date(startDate);
            stopDate.setMonth(stopDate.getMonth() + parseInt(duration));
            stopDate = DateFormat.format.date(stopDate,"MM/dd/yyyy");
            $("#end_date label").html(stopDate);
            $("#end_date").show();

            var today = DateFormat.format.date(new Date(),"MM/dd/yyyy");
            todayObj = new Date(today);
            startDateObj = new Date(startDate);
            todayTimestamp = Date.UTC(todayObj.getFullYear(),todayObj.getMonth(), todayObj.getDate());
            startDateTimestamp = Date.UTC(startDateObj.getFullYear(),startDateObj.getMonth(), startDateObj.getDate());

            if (todayTimestamp >= startDateTimestamp) {
                 $('#getting-started').countdown(stopDate, function(event) {
                    $(this).html(event.strftime('%Y year %m month %d days %H:%M:%S'));
                 });
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

My html code is as follows:

```
<div>
<p>Start Date: <input type="text" id="start_date"></p>
<p>Period: <input type="text" id="period" placeholder="No. of Months"></p>
<p id="end_date">End Date: <label></label></p>
<p><input type="button" value="Add Counter" id="setCounter" /></p>  
</div>
<div id="getting-started"></div>
```

Comment: What specifically is wrong with the year?

Comment: If the user enters 15 months in the duration then it gives the correct end date but the counter gives the output as, 1 year 15 months ...